# d3.js mercator projection to NYC map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, map-projections, mercator

I am making a map of the boroughs in NYC and I can't seem to get the projection right: the only thing I get is a tiny map.

I tried recreating [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5126418) example, which only made the console go crazy with errors, I suspect because there was something off about the equation.

When I was trying to get albers to work, I tried out the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628382/scaling-d3-js-projections) question, and still I could not get the map to work.

```
  With 960/500 height and width, I used: var projection = d3.geo.albers().center([40.71, 73.98]).parallels([29.5, 45.5]).scale(10000).translate([(width) / 2, (height)/2]);
```

Right now, I am using a transverse Mercator, with the code below, and the topojson I created using one of [these](http://nycdata.pediacities.com/group/nyc-shape-files) files.

```
  var width = 960,
   height = 500;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  d3.json("nyc-borough.json", function(error, nyb) {

  var boroughs = topojson.feature(nyb, nyb.objects["nyc-borough-boundaries-polygon"]).features;

  var projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator()
.scale(1600)
.rotate([73 + 58 / 60, -48 - 47 / 60]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

g.append("g")
.attr("id", "boroughs")
.selectAll(".state")
.data(boroughs)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.name; })
.attr("d", path);

});
```

Please, please halp :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a bl.ock with the NYC boroughs [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6646844).  You were on the right path with WSG84/Mercator as that was what the original data was in, as a quick check in QGIS demonstrated.

[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) was also good checking the centre of the data, again which came out to be [-73.94, 40.70].  Note that these are the opposite way round to your co-ordinates which were lat and long, but d3 needs long and lat as discussed here in the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-_projection).  The other thing to look out for is the negatives.  North is positive so latitude in the northern hemisphere is positive and negative in the southern hemisphere.  For the east and west hemispheres its east that's positive. Of course this only matters for the global projections the USA Albers wouldn't have negatives for the USA.  Oh, and no discussion on Projections would be complete without a look at [Jason Davies work](http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/).

If you want to use a different projection to the projection your data is in I generally think it's better to preprocess your data into that projection and QGIS is a great tool for that but there are many others such as gdal.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I ended up using the New Jersey example, using its according JSON, and just moving the map to New York's coordinates. I then printed out the scale and transform that was calculated dynamically, but this of course spit out non-neat numbers. This ended up working anyway, but your answer is much more helpful. +1 also because I don't think there is that much info on this out there!